# Elements of a relation

Tags: relations

So I proved this was a relation, but I'm having real trouble identifying the elements of the relation. I'm not quite sure what I am supposed to do. Are the elements of the relation [(0,3)] all of the solutions to 0 = 3c? Any help would be great. I'm very confused on how to proceed. Any tips/websites you could offer me would help so much.

[image]

http://puu.sh/nsOXA/7b4a79dc31.png

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, but it seems you may have sidetracked yourself by unnecessarily eliminating the $d$. The elements of $[(0,3)]$ are all pairs $(c,d)$ which are solutions to the equation $0d=3c$.

Comment: Thanks for the help! so (0,0) (1,0) ect. ect. And are all these different sets? Because it asks me to "Prove these two sets are equal" I was under the impression that it was one set?

Comment: $(c,d)=(1,0)$ is not a solution of the equation $0d=3c$.